# my alert size is not showing correctly in android?

Tags: android

My alert width is too short.

screenshot:

[image]

Here is design xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Hari"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/customer_id1"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="96"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/mobile"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="7826963223"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/pickup_address"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="ponmeni Muniyandi kovil main road"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Accept"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarywhite"
            android:text="@string/btn_accept" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Decline"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_black"
            android:text="@string/btn_decline"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarywhite" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your code for alert dialog

Comment: first replace fill_parent by match_parent because fill_parent deprecated [see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) and show me java code where you inflate this dialogue

Comment: as a side note, i believe the decline button should always be on the side of the back button. also note, that this varies per device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this set Dialog Layout hight and width Programatically using  `Window`

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog.show();
```

and also use use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to your `LinearLayout`

> beacuse `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`  This value is deprecated starting in API Level 8 and replaced by `MATCH_PARENT`.

Answer (score -1):

You can control your alert box size by this :

```
 alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(100, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```